# Dplyr filter out if row meets multiple conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

How to filter rows that have value x in column j and value y in column j+1

so in the mtcars example lets say i want to filter out the rows where am =1 and gear = 5. The code below does not do the trick:

```
mtcars %>% filter(am != 1 & gear != 5)
```

Thanks

Jelle

Comment: Perhaps you have loaded another package that masks `filter`.  Try `mtcars %>% dplyr::filter(am != 1, gear != 5)`

Comment: You can make a table with the combos you want to drop and anti join, see `?anti_join`. Also, in this case, there's `!(am==1 & gear==5)` -- which is not equivalent to the condition written in OP.

Comment: @akrun, this is not the case, your code also does not work since it filters out all am!=1 and not when both are true (am!=1 & gear != 5)

Comment: A nice solution is maybe to paste the two columns together in a new column and filter this new column